# Drupal + Views Slideshowplugin?

Tags: drupal, view, slideshow

I have a question, but the problem is, I can't show the page right now, because it's only on my local server. I will try to explain it as good as possible.

I've got a view that makes my frontpage have the full content of my nodes. So you see a node(in this case an embeded youtube link). You can then go to the next node via "next" or to the previous one via "previous", etc. The problem I have and I don't know how to fix is:

I got a gallery below(another view), of all my nodes, so you can either click through the prev and next buttons, or click on one of the pictures in the "gallery". But when i click on the galery, it goes to the node links so lets say "site.com/node/44".

Is there a way I can go to the node/44 page and still be able to click prev and next? And moreover, can I use the Slideshow plugin by views with changing links? Because it's just says "#" in the url...  Like it does with the main content when i click "prev" and "next"?

I hope you can understand what this is about :-). If not, please feel free to ask for further information.

Answer (score 0):

So your explanation is a little "garbly" so here's my somewhat 'not-so-garbly' response:
Sounds like your understanding of views is a little low. Make sure you're Displaying fields in your view and not just full nodes or teasers.

Next, if your desire is to show the gallery on all the nodes of the same type, you can so by creating a block display in views and configuring that block to show up ONLY on the node type you desire.

It gets complicated when you (which appears to be your desire) want the view to start from the last point you were viewing. This will require rewriting the field (this is available via the field configure form) which contains the image. You'll have to add a parameter (probably the current nid) which can be added, hidden, then accessed as a token via the Views Fields interface as well.

I don't remember exactly how to get the view to display the current (or next) slide by default once it's clicked.. but this is probably how I'd do it:
  pick up that parameter in JS / JQ and use it to find the slide you want to display... then fire the JS function needed to display the desired slide.